# Resizing fedora LiveCD partitions

Tags: fedora, live-cd, qubes-os

I'm using Fedora to create Qubes installation media for a Lenovo machine per their directions [here](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/thinkpad-troubleshooting/#instructions-to-create-usb-installation-medium-for-newer-uefi-only-thinkpads). There is some weirdness with UEFI on newer lenovos that require special accommodations in the installation LiveCD. However, the Fedora Media Writer automatically creates a home partition that is only 1.7 GB, which is not enough space to download/store the ISO for Qubes (~4.3 GB). It looks like Qubes ISO needs to be on the same partition in order to create the media. How do I either (1) resize this partition so I can actually place the Qubes ISO on it or (2) give myself enough space in the first place to actually place the ISO on the drive? I have no idea how to resize partitions on LiveCDs as I don't understand their partition structure.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by:

- downloading the Qubes ISO file onto a second flash drive
- creating a ramdisk in the Fedora LiveCD and copying the ISO there
- unmounting the second flash drive
- and then writing Qubes onto the flash drive as a live CD per the directions in the linked article above.

Not ideal but better than using parted on a liveCD. If anyone else gets stuck, I can provide more detailed directions.